# Is $\chi=1$ for rational surfaces over an aribitrary field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

I've found in many textbooks that if $S$ is a smooth rational surface over an algebraically closed field, then $\chi(S,\mathcal{O}_S)=1$ (more precisely, $h^0=1$ and $h^1=h^2=0$).

I'm trying to find out if this is also true over arbitrary fields ($\Bbb{Q}$, for example), but I had difficulty to finding answers online.

If this is true, is there a standard reference for this kind of question?

If this is false in general, what's the reason behind it?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give a citation for the first claim? I haven't heard this before and it sounds interesting, but I'm not sure which one of my many textbooks matches your many textbooks.

Comment: This is false. For example, an abelian surface has $\chi=0$.

Comment: @Mohan, I'm so sorry, I meant a _rational_ surface

Comment: $\chi$ is a birational. Invariant. What definition of rational surface are you using?

Comment: @Mohan by rational I mean birational to $\Bbb{P}^2$. I didn't know $\chi$ was a birational invariant, I'm glad there's a straight-forward answer, thank you

Comment: One more question just occured to me: people from arithmetic geometry like to talk about $\Bbb{Q}$-rational vs. geometrically rational surfaces, i.e. $S$ being birational to $\Bbb{P}^2_\Bbb{Q}$ versus  $\overline{S}:=S\times_\Bbb{Q}\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ being birational to $\Bbb{P}^2_{\overline{\Bbb{Q}}}$. If we assume $S$ is geometrically rational, then for sure $\chi(\overline{S})=1$. But is it the case that $\chi(S)=1$ too?

Comment: The natural map $H^i(S)\to H^i(\overline{S})$ is injective.